# returning a replaced field in a list of namedtuples in a namedtuple

Tags: list, python-3.x, iteration, tuples

I have a Restaurant and Dish type namedtuple defined below:

```
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone menu')
Dish = namedtuple('Dish', 'name price calories')

r1 = Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433', [Dish('Mee Krob', 12.50, 500),
                                                    Dish('Larb Gai', 11.00, 450)])
```

I need to change the price of the dish by 2.50. I have the following code:

```
def Restaurant_raise_prices(rest):
result = []
for item in rest:
    for dish in item.menu:
        dish = dish._replace(price = dish.price + 2.50)
        result.append(item)
return result
```

It replaces the price field and returns the Dish namedtuple:

```
[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=15.0, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=13.5, calories=450)]
```

How can I change my code to add the restaurant as well?

but it only returns the Dish. What if I wanted the entire Restaurant too? How can I make the change so that the output is:

```
Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433', [Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=15.0, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=13.5, calories=450)])
```

Comment: Don’t use named tuples for this. Also, your code does not produce that output… Replacing `dish` will *not* update the (immutable) tuple within the restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

Named tuples are first and foremost tuples, and as such **immutable**. That means that you cannot modify the existing objects. If you wanted to change them, you would have to create *new* tuples containing the new values and replace all references to the old tuple with that new tuple.

The code you are using does not work for that, since `dish = dish._replace(…)` will replace the value of `dish` with a new tuple, but changing what `dish` references will not update the reference that exists within the restaurant tuple. Also, with the line `result.append(item)` being part of the inner loop where you iterate over the dishes, you end up with multiple (unchanged!) copies of the same restaurant tuple in the result.

You could change it like this to make it work (btw. assuming you only pass a single restaurant to the function—so you only need one loop for the dishes):

```
def restaurant_raise_prices (rest):
    dishes = []
    for dish in rest.menu:
        dishes.append(dish._replace(price=dish.price + 2.50))
    rest = rest._replace(menu=dishes)
    return rest
```

This will return a new restaurant with the changed prices for each dish (note that `r1` won’t reflect this change):

```
>>> r1
Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=12.5, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=11.0, calories=450)])
>>> restaurant_raise_prices(r1)
Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', menu=[Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=15.0, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=13.5, calories=450)])
```

---

A cleaner way however would be to introduce proper types that are mutable, so you can make this a bit better. After all, restaurants are objects that can change: They can modify their menu all the time, without becoming a new restaurant. So it makes sense to have the restaurants—as well as the dishes—be mutable objects instead:

```
class Restaurant:
    def __init__ (self, name, cuisine, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.cuisine = cuisine
        self.phone = phone
        self.menu = []

    def __str__ (self):
        return '{} ({}) - {} ({} dishes)'.format(self.name, self.cuisine, self.phone, len(self.menu))

class Dish:
    def __init__ (self, name, price, calories):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.calories = calories

    def raise_price (self, amount):
        self.price += amount

    def __str__ (self):
        return '{} (price: {}, calories: {})'.format(self.name, self.price, self.calories)
```

```
>>> r1 = Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433')
>>> r1.menu.append(Dish('Mee Krob', 12.50, 500))
>>> r1.menu.append(Dish('Larb Gai', 11.00, 450))

>>> print(r1)
Thai Dishes (Thai) - 334-4433 (2 dishes)
>>> for dish in r1.menu:
        print(dish)

Mee Krob (price: 12.5, calories: 500)
Larb Gai (price: 11.0, calories: 450)

>>> for dish in r1.menu:
        dish.raise_price(2.50)
        print(dish)

Mee Krob (price: 15.0, calories: 500)
Larb Gai (price: 13.5, calories: 450)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That helped a lot. Is there a way for the function to not include the `menu=` part? That is the output to be exactly like the input(plus the price change).            `Restaurant('Thai Dishes', 'Thai', '334-4433', [Dish(name='Mee Krob', price=15.0, calories=500), Dish(name='Larb Gai', price=13.5, calories=450)])`

Comment: The output from the namedtuple is fixed and will always include the attribute names explicitely, you cannot modify that. If you used custom types, you could adjust the output as I have shown though.